# Problem with refreshing the page for mobile version

Tags: support

The page doesn’t refresh in case posting an answer or comments in the mobile version iOS 11.3. It submits the post successfully but the page turns out white. Swiping up or down doesn’t force the refreshing. Any suggestions?!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @AndrewT. I’m using the app.

Comment: Stack Exchange app, or Stack Overflow app? That said, [no one on SE is currently working on the mobile apps though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301764/future-plans-for-the-stack-exchange-ios-app-beta-version/301766#comment983878_301766)...

Comment: @AndrewT.  Stack Exchange